# Power Source for Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, power

So I have SIM900 Shield and Arduino Uno and they have both power jack, is it possible to power one of them using one power jack and connect it's power with another? If it is possible, I sincerely need the explanation.

I've research about the VIN pin of Arduino but I didnt quite get it and can't take the risk that I might fry the board since Im new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what voltage the devices run at and what their current draw is from the power supply versus what voltage & current your power supply provides.

If everything runs at 3.3V or 5V and minimal amps then you're good to go.

Read the datasheet for each device and for your power supply.